# Reading using urllib2.urlopen()

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to use urllib2 module in python to fetch content of a url.

Let's say my url is "http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-01/ass01_12.html"

When I try to fetch it's content using these two simple line it gives me the complete html content of it.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
print(content)
```

However when I redefine this thing inside a function it return me an html without the content of the body tag in it.

```
def getContentURL(url):
    ''' returns the html content of the given url '''
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    content = response.read()
    return content

content = getContentURL(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(conten) #added in edit
print(content)
```

I only get this much.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 <meta content="Bradley Kjell kjell at ieee dot org " name="author"/>
 <meta content="2007" name="copyright"/>
 <meta content="index,follow" name="robots"/>
 <title>
  CHAPTER 1 — Introduction
 </title>
 <link href="../AssemblyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening ? I am unable to understand this strange behavior.

=============================== Edit ===============================================
So I wrote a test.py with the same thing and it works perfectly.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib

def getContentURL(url):
    ''' returns the content of the given url in text format '''
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    content = response.read()
    return content

url = "http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-01/ass01_1.html"

content = getContentURL(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(content) #prints everything
print(soup) #prints without the body's inner html

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #print(link)
    print(link.get('href'))
```

However same lines of code in my original code doesn't works, which has some other stuffs in the beginning. The link to it is https://github.com/kumar116/WebsiteCopier/blob/master/web_save.py. Posting a link as it's big to paste here.

The only change of line that you will see there is I am printing 
print(soup.prettify()) or print(soup).

Which eats up everything inside my body tag.

I need the soup in order to be able to parse the html.

Comment: do u wan to do web scrapping

Comment: I am trying the get all the links within the body tag of this html. So yes, web scraping. I am using BeautifulSoup for that. But as long as I don't get everything in this html, I won't be able to do that.

Comment: check ur function names getContent() .its wrong call. change n try its coming

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Typo. Corrected. I don't use any function named getContent()

Comment: you probably trying to read it too often. Try its google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-01/ass01_12.html

Comment: But then why the two lines always print correctly when outside the function however often I read them. My whole project is here if somebody wants to clone it and test it by themselves (https://github.com/kumar116/WebsiteCopier). Only when I put them inside a function it starts behaving weirdly.

Comment: i donno y dint u get . i am getting correct results.try again n see

Comment: So here is where the problem is, I was passing the content to the BeautifulSoup and it's hiding everything under body tag ? Now, why is it doing that ?

content = getContentURL(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(content)

Comment: try: `print(inspect.getsource(getContentURL))` What do you see? Is it the same `url`? Do you assign to `content` after at some point?

Comment: I assign the content to BeautifulSoup constructor and everything changes after that. Still looking for reasons as to why is it does that. I highly suggest someone looking at my code on GitHub because the same lines of code work on a different file but not in my original code.

Comment: [edit] your question and add this essential information to it. `print(content)` before you pass it to `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Sure, I am re-editing some parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you may use a bash script to catch the content of an URL, you would get the text only output  from a html out

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

lynx -dump -nolist $1 | tr 'ÑÁÉÍÓÚ' 'ñáéíóú' | sed -e 's/ñ/n/g' | sed -e 's/á/a/g' | sed -e 's/é/e/g' | sed -e 's/í/i/g' | sed -e 's/ó/o/g' | sed -e 's/ú/u/g' | tr -sc 'A-Za-z0-9.,;:?!()\n"' '
 ' | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
```

This code have to be in a file.sh and called from your code

```
import subprocess as sp

text = sp.check_output(['sh', "%s/%s" % ('file.sh'), URL])
```